# Проблема с PHP - sleep и foreach

Tags: php

Имеется массив ссылок. Нужно добавить их в базу данных, но сначала проверить из файла-отчета.

```
public function query_page() {
    $data_link = array(
        "/orsk/doma_dachi_kottedzhi/dom_60_m_na_uchastke_5_sot._577934693",
        "/orsk/doma_dachi_kottedzhi/dom_130_m_na_uchastke_6_sot._754499329",
        "/orsk/doma_dachi_kottedzhi/kottedzh_295_m_na_uchastke_7_sot._553062836",
        "/orsk/doma_dachi_kottedzhi/dom_40.1_m_na_uchastke_3_sot._767494601",
        "/orsk/doma_dachi_kottedzhi/dom_54_m_na_uchastke_10_sot._783057977",
    );

    $i=0;

    foreach ($data_link as $advert){
        if ($i == 5) break; 
        $inspection = $this->inspection($advert); //тут проверяем из файла-отчета
        if ($inspection)
            $this->error = true;
        else
            $this->error = false;

        if (!$this->error) {
            $mas_save["link"] = $advert;
            $db_query = forming_db_query_indexmas("db_advert", $mas_save, "new", "id_advert");
            $q_ident = obr_db_query($db_query); //пишем в базу
        }

        $i++;

        sleep(9);
    }
}

private function inspection($link) {
    $result = false;

    $text_inspection = file_get_contents("result.txt");
    $text_inspection = explode("\n", $text_inspection); //получаем массив ссылок из файла отчета

    if (sizeof($text_inspection) > 0) {
        foreach ($text_inspection as $get_link){
            if ($get_link == $link) {
                $result = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return $result;

}
```

На данный момент у меня есть уже в файле-отчете 3 первых ссылки из массива. Должны добавится последние 2, но не добавляются. Получаю ошибку с базой данных.
Стоит мне сделать sleep до 5 секунд и все работает хорошо.
Подскажите, в чем проблема?

Comment: 1. Какая ошибка с базой? 2. Если этот код - копи-паста из исходника, то в методе `query_page` не хватает одной фигурной скобки, которая закрыла бы тело метода. 3. Зачем тут вообще `sleep()`?..

Comment: по поводу скобки -  просто забыл тут добавить.. Она есть .. 
А вот ошибка с базой не детализируется .. Пишет ,что просто ошибка  с базой.

Sleep , т.к ссылки парсяться в этом методе. Я просто показал в готовом виде

Comment: что у вас в obr_db_query?

Comment: show create table на таблицу, в которую инсерт идет, пожалуйста

Comment: нужно видеть содержимео методов forming_db_query_indexmas и obr_db_query...попробуйте убрать /orsk/doma_dachi_kottedzhi/dom_40.1_m_na_uchastke_3_sot._767494601 этот из списка...тогда вместо 3х добавится 4е ?